# How to use secret value in kubernetes annotations

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I have a following secret

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: my-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  my-value: "dGVzdC1kYXRh"
```

I want to use above secrets value in following kubernetes code:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  annotations:
    my-annotation: [{\"key\":\"<use-secret-value-here>\"}]
```

Can someone help me with kustomize? I tried many ways.

Comment: That would kinda defeat the purpose of the Secret in the 1st place if it's value is visible in an annotation.

Comment: With or without Kustomize, there's no out of the box of doing this anyway. What's the context?